# Is it possible to change the direction that a PVC door opens?

Tags: doors

This is my PVC door. I want it to open the other way, so that the handle is on the left, and the hinges are on the right, as indicated by the arrows in the picture.

[image]

This is a picture of the frame and the mechanisms that have to slot into it. I could unscrew the metal plate attached to the frame in the first photo, and screw it into the other side of the frame upside down.

[image]

However, the door itself looks more difficult and as if it would require a specialist - or it might be easier to get a new door. The side currently facing outside needs to face outside after changes - it looks as if someone would have to dismantle the door, flip over the 'filling of the sandwich' with the mechanism in, and put it back together again, and also probably get a new handle (I don't have a key for this door, so needs a new handle anyway).

[image][image][image]

OTOH, cost for a new door is £450 to £800 in 2022 according to [this website].[6](https://householdquotes.co.uk/how-much-is-a-upvc-front-door/) That's for a plain white PVC door without any nice glass in it, which this door has. Is the cost of 'flipping' the door going to be more or less?

Comment: The problem is that where the hinges and door handle is will leave decent size holes in the frame/door.  Very few doors are made to make switching easy, usually easier to change the door from opening in to opening out.

Comment: If I do that the door will hit people in the face when I open it

Comment: Not much of a problem if you don't like the people.  The hinges are usually easy, since they do not show much.  Most door handles have at least one ~2 inch hole and maybe two smaller holes that is hard to hide/patch.  It is mainly the look of the door after that is the hard part, the moving the handle and hinges is usually easy if you don't mind a hole left in the door.

Comment: You'll also have the door not able to fully open as it will be blocked by the wall, leaving you with a smaller "open door" opening than the present arrangement where it can swing out of the way. Depending on the size of the door and local requirements, that might prevent you from being able to actually do this, legally, if it reduces access too much (fire, ambulance, etc...) and you might not be able to get furniture in the house now out of the house when you move...

Comment: It appears that these are surface mount hinges. These will leave additional holes in the face of the door that will be difficult to patch. To @Ecnerwal's point, you might consider removing the door from the frame then simply turning it around and putting the hinge side in the opening. This will allow you to see how far out into the room the door & handle will be. As noted, this might not be enough for code compliance, and even if it is compliant, it might become impractical for moving larger things (like you on a stretcher should there be an emergency) in and out of the house.

Comment: Get real quotes from the trades. My gut is that trying to flip will be almost as expensive as replacing.